# Caching array data used in UITableView to save memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, core-data, memory-management

I am retrieving a JSON string back from a server and letting RestKit parse it and map it to objects and return the array of objects to show in the `UITableView`. Unfortunately there are 3 arrays of similar data spread across 3 `UITableView` accessed with a `UITabView`.

I am saving the objects into coredata but am having trouble figuring out how to limit the amount of objects loaded into memory in the array because they currently grow anytime the user refreshes the tableviews. I can't use a `NSFetchedResultesController` because I need access to the data array to add and remove objects at will.

Kind of stuck on where to go from here, any suggestions would be great!

Comment: What seemed to be the problem here was the RestKit library using a TON of memory when mapping the objects etc. It ended up being more efficient for me to save the data (in this case) as JSON text and parsing them when needed for the 3 different arrays of data as well as limiting the amount of objects which were saved and just fetching older ones if needed from the server (when scrolling downward)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch first 20 the reload tableview. For next batch next 20 from last object from array

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

And use the fetchLimit property

```
[request setFetchLimit:20];
```